# Convert Text to Numbers in SQLite

Tags: sqlite

I have a sqlite  DB with a table with the following structure LocationName  Latitude Longitude all defined as varchar. How i can construct a sql statement to get all the locations with a specific lat range given latitude in decimal. is there a way to do that convert from varchar to decimal value on the fly ? or i have to step through the return statements  and do the conversion manually

Comment: SQLite supports types other than varchar (text) - http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html. Why not store the values in real columns?

Comment: It would be far more efficient to store the values as actual numbers in the database.

Comment: I have been given the db in that formate i cant change. Wish i can :)

Answer (score 126):

See "CAST expressions" at http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html.

```
SELECT CAST('3.02' as decimal)
-- they aren't real decimals in sqlite, though. beware floats.
```

Comment: Oh thanks , i will give that a Try. What if the column for latitude for example is defined as N320515 . is there a way to do the same ?

Comment: there is `substr` to extract substrings, and `case..when..end` to convert 'N/S' to 1/-1. you'll get a hairy expression, but it's possible. UPD: and make sure to test on all possible hemispheres :)

Comment: Thanks Again , i will dig more into how to create that sql statement.