# How to turn a string of numbers being stored in SQL back into integers in Python?

Tags: python, arrays, string, sqlite, integer

So I've got "1,5,12" stored as a string in a SQL database, I've managed to get the string into python using cursor.fetchone etc.

How do I separate this "1,5,12" string into say an array of integers? If possible I want to be able to call the individual integers as indexes in an array.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [sqlite Convert Text to Numbers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14308467/sqlite-convert-text-to-numbers)

Comment: Use [**`ast.literal_eval`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval)

Answer (score 0):

Use a list comprehension and `str.split`:

```
data = "1,5,12"
example_list = [int(x) for x in data.split(',')]
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you string was stored in a variable, you could do something like this;

```
data_result="1,5,12"
int_result=list(map(int,data_result.split(",")))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can [`split()`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) your string on the commas, to get a list of strings. These can then be turned to integer numbers using the [`int()`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#int) function inside a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).

To catch conversion errors, this can be wrapped in a [`try ... except`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions) block, especially if the original string comes from external/user input.

Example:

```
string_of_ints= "1,5,12"
try:
    list_of_ints = [int(x) for x in string_of_ints.split(",")]
except ValueError:
    print("Value Error")
```

This yields:

```
[1, 5, 12]
```

Comment: Thanks for the notice, I was lazy. I improved my post.

Answer (score 0):

First split the string into a list using the `,` delimiter `mylist.split(',')`. Then convert each member of that list into an integer. You now have a list of integers.

Use a list comprehension:

```
results = [int(i) for i in results]
```

e.g.

> > > mylist = ['1, 2, 3']
> > >       results = mylist.split(',')
> > >       results = [int(i) for i in results]
> > >       results
> > >           [1, 2, 3]

Answer (score 0):

Use [**`ast.literal_eval`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval):

```
>>> from ast import literal_eval
>>> s = '1,5,12'
>>> literal_eval(s)
(1, 5, 12)

>>> list(literal_eval(s))
[1, 5, 12]
```